# Programmatically find your Script ID

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a Google Apps Script which must be registered with an OAuth2 service, which in turn needs the redirect_url to complete authorization.  This redirect_url requires as a component the Script ID.

Is there a way that I can programmatically read the Script ID property from within my Add-on script, so that I can present the user a full redirect_url to copy when registering their spreadsheet?

Comment: If it's available programmatically, it should be well-documented in Apps Script documentation, yes? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I was unable to find this by searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been unable to find the API by searching for ScriptID or "Script ID" -- but there is an API: ScriptApp.getScriptId()